# ADL fails to find friend function and causes a linker error

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

**Update**: [O'Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3893262/oneil) identified the careless error: I defined `operator!=` with `const` but left out the `const`s in the declaration. This also of course explains why placing the full function definition in the class declaration originally fixed the problem.

I'm attempting to implement a simple standard library for C++ (for learning purposes), and I'm encountering a linker error when invoking `operator==` and `operator!=` associated with an iterator through a vector.

*Note: I've included a lot of the code to be thorough, but you should be able to just look at `vector::insert`, `operator!=(iterator, iterator)` and the contents of `main`, in addition to the linking error stated at the bottom, to figure out the issue.*

I've implemented vector.hpp as such, leaving out some definitions which I don't think are necessary to identify the reason for the bug:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
#define VECTOR_HPP


#include "utility.hpp"   // stl::size_t
#include "memory.hpp"    // stl::Allocator
#include "iterator.hpp"


namespace stl {

template <typename T, typename A>
class VectorBase
{
public:
    typedef T           ValueType;
    typedef T&          Reference;
    typedef const T&    ConstReference;
    typedef T*          Pointer;
    typedef const T*    ConstPointer;
    typedef A           AllocatorType;
    typedef stl::size_t SizeType;

    VectorBase(SizeType, const AllocatorType&);
    ~VectorBase() { delete[] elements_; }

    AllocatorType   allocator_;
    Pointer         elements_ = nullptr;
    SizeType        size_ = 0;
    SizeType        capacity_ = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename A = stl::Allocator<T> >
class Vector : private VectorBase<T, A>
{
public:
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::AllocatorType    AllocatorType;
    typedef stl::BidirectionalIterator<T>               Iterator;
    typedef const stl::BidirectionalIterator<T>         ConstIterator;
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::ValueType        ValueType;
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::Reference        Reference;
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::ConstReference   ConstReference;
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::Pointer          Pointer;
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::ConstPointer     ConstPointer;
    typedef Vector<T, A>                                Self;
    typedef typename VectorBase<T, A>::SizeType         SizeType;

    // CONSTRUCTORS & DESTRUCTORS
    Vector(SizeType = 0,
           ValueType&& = ValueType(),
           const AllocatorType& = AllocatorType());
    Vector(const Self&);
    Vector(Self&&);
    Self& operator=(Self);

    // OPERATORS
    Reference       operator[](SizeType);
    ConstReference  operator[](SizeType) const;

    // MODIFIERS
    Iterator    insert(Iterator, ValueType);
    void        pop_back();
    void        push_back(ValueType);
    void        reserve(SizeType);

    template <typename T_, typename A_>
    friend void swap(Vector<T_, A_>&, Vector<T_, A_>&);

    // ACCESSORS
    Iterator        begin();
    ConstIterator   cbegin() const;
    Iterator        end();
    ConstIterator   cend() const;
};

template <typename T, typename A>
auto Vector<T, A>::insert(Iterator iterator, ValueType val) -> Iterator
{
    if (this->size_ == this->capacity_)
        reserve(2 * this->size_);
    for (auto it = this->end(); it != iterator; --it) {    // this is the problem line
    // for (auto it = this->end(); stl::operator!=(it, iterator); --it) {  // this fixes the linking issue
        auto temp(it);
        *temp = *--it;
        ++it;
    }
    *iterator = stl::move(val);
    return iterator;
}

// ...

}   // namespace stl

#endif  // VECTOR_HPP
```

And iterator.hpp is implemented

```
#ifndef ITERATOR_HPP
#define ITERATOR_HPP


#include "utility.hpp"


namespace stl {

template <typename T>
struct BidirectionalIterator
{
    typedef T                           ValueType;
    typedef T*                          Pointer;
    typedef const T*                    ConstPointer;
    typedef T&                          Reference;
    typedef const T&                    ConstReference;
    typedef BidirectionalIterator<T>    Self;

    BidirectionalIterator(Pointer ptr = nullptr) : current_(ptr) { }
    BidirectionalIterator(const Self& that) : current_(that.current_) { }
    BidirectionalIterator(Self&&);
    Self&       operator=(Self);

    Self&           operator++();
    Self            operator++(int);
    Self&           operator--();
    Self            operator--(int);
    Reference       operator*();
    ConstReference  operator*() const;
    Pointer         operator->();
    ConstPointer    operator->() const;

    template <typename T_>
    friend void swap(BidirectionalIterator<T_>&,
                     BidirectionalIterator<T_>&);

    template <typename T_>
    friend bool operator==(BidirectionalIterator<T_>&,
                           BidirectionalIterator<T_>&);

    template <typename T_>
    friend bool operator!=(BidirectionalIterator<T_>&,
                           BidirectionalIterator<T_>&);

    Pointer current_;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const BidirectionalIterator<T>& first,
                const BidirectionalIterator<T>& second)
{ return first.current_ == second.current_; }

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(const BidirectionalIterator<T>& first,
                const BidirectionalIterator<T>& second)
{ return !(first == second); }

// ...

}   // namespace stl

#endif  // ITERATOR_HPP
```

And finally test.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/vector.hpp"


int main(void)
{
    stl::Vector<int> v;
    for (stl::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    v.pop_back();

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto it = v.begin();
    ++it;
    v.insert(it, 100);

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Then when I attempt to compile with:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11   // I get the same issue with g++
```

I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "bool stl::operator!=<int>(stl::BidirectionalIterator<int>&, stl::BidirectionalIterator<int>&)", referenced from:
      stl::Vector<int, stl::Allocator<int> >::insert(stl::BidirectionalIterator<int>, int) in test-dbe290.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

However, if I take out `v.insert(it, 100);` in `main` the program links fine. Furthermore, if I leave `v.insert(it, 100);` in, and fix `vector::insert` as noted in the comments above (namely, changing `operator!=` from an unqualified function call to a `stl` qualified function call), the entire program links fine and produces the expected result. It appears that I'm failing to invoke ADL correctly, so I looked at the details of [adl according to cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) to find the additional namespaces added to the lookup and found:

> 2) For arguments of class type (including union), the set consists of
>       ...
>       d) The innermost enclosing namespaces in the classes added to the set

Since `BidirectionalIterator` is enclosed in `stl`, I assumed that `stl::operator!=` should be included in the lookup and wouldn't need to be explicitly stated.

Another interesting thing is that if I change `operator!=` to be completely defined within the `BidirectionalIterator` class, i.e.:

```
template <typename T_>
friend bool operator!=(BidirectionalIterator<T_>& first,
                       BidirectionalIterator<T_>& second)
    { return !(first == second); }
```

and reinstate the previous code that caused an error: `for (auto it = this->end(); it != iterator; --it) {` in `vector::insert`, the `insert` invocation in `main` works fine, but the other for loops (i.e. `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)`) cause the following compiler error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('stl::BidirectionalIterator<int>' and 'Iterator' (aka 'BidirectionalIterator<int>'))
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
```

Why isn't the compiler able to find `operator!=` in `stl` without an explicit scope resolution operator? Additionally, why does fully defining the friend function in the class declaration of `BidirectionalIterator` solve the first problem but cause a compiler error for instances of `operator!=` directly in `main`?

Comment: You forgot the `const`s between declaration and implementation.

Comment: You would have probably found the problem that @O'Neil identified had you tried to create a [mcve].